# Best probability density function to use for the prior of a variance parameter in Bayesian inference

Tags: bayesian, inference, density-function, prior, variational-inference

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78629/226254) provided some good general advice, but in my specific case I want to create a model of my prior beliefs about the *variance* of a normally-distributed random variable:

$$x \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_x^2)$$

I want an appropriate parameterized function $f$ for my beliefs about $\sigma_x^2$:

$$\sigma_x^2 \sim f(\hat{\sigma_x}^2, ...)$$

where $\hat{\sigma_x}^2$ is my prior 'best guess'.

In the answer linked above it suggests using the Gamma distribution for positive real parameters. However, I read on wikipedia.org that the [inverse-chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-chi-squared_distribution) can be used in Bayesian inference:

> as the prior and posterior distribution for an unknown variance of the normal distribution.

But there is also the [scaled inverse chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaled_inverse_chi-squared_distribution) and the [Inverse-gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution) so now I am confused which is the best one to use.

My application is not rocket science so whichever is the most common and/or most appropriate in general.

Comment: The answer is straightforward : there is no "best prior" unless one enjoys such precise information as to have no choice about the prior. A Bayesian analysis is conditional upon a (chosen rather than given) prior.

Comment: Well, there are certainly very poor ones! Such as a normal distribution in this case. Suppose my estimate of the std. deviation is s and I am sure that the probability of the true std. deviation is between 0.5s and 2s is 50%. Is there a pdf for the variance (or std dev.) that would satisfy these conditions?  This would actually be a useful prior that I can explain.